# "The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies)" error WCF REST

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

I have a RESTful service that doesn't work, despite I verify all the code: web.config, the Iservic and the implementation:

IServiceImport:

```
 namespace SysLap.Services.Web.ImportAutoLiasse
{
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceImportAutoLiasse
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    string GetData(int value);   
}
}
```

ServiceImport.svc.cs:

```
namespace SysLap.Services.Web.ImportAutoLiasse
 {
   public class ServiceImportAutoLiasse: IServiceImportAutoLiasse
   {
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
   }
 }
```

Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <!--SOAP-->
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServBehavior" name="SysLap.Services.Web.ImportAutoLiasse.ServiceImportAutoLiasse">
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="SysLap.Services.Web.ImportAutoLiasse.IServiceImportAutoLiasse" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />

    <!--REST-->
    <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="SysLap.Services.Web.ImportAutoLiasse.IServiceImportAutoLiasse" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

When I test SOAP, it works well,
but if I test the wcf REST:

```
https://localhost:44355/ServiceImportAutoLiasse.svc/rest/GetData?value=19
```

I have this error :

```
  HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, 
 had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure 
 that it is spelled correctly.
```

[image]
In other hand , I have other wcf project contains services as SOAP and REST and I compare the code from it and all is good !

I get these information when I use POSTMAN:

```
[EndpointNotFoundException]: There was no channel actively listening at &#39;https://localhost:44355/ServiceImportAutoLiasse.svc/rest/GetData?value=19&#39;. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
[HttpException]: There was no channel actively listening at &#39;https://localhost:44355/ServiceImportAutoLiasse.svc/rest/GetData?value=19&#39;. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory.ServiceHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
```

How can I fix it ? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name property and the contract of the service cannot be changed at will. It is supposed to be the actual fully qualified service implementation class and the service interface, which consists of the namespace, a period, and then the type name. For example `WcfService1.Service1`.
Therefore, the above interface definition and service implementation don’t correspond to the below properties in the services section.

```
<services>
  <!--SOAP-->
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServBehavior" name="SysLap.Services.Web.ImportAutoLiasse.ServiceImportAutoLiasse">
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="SysLap.Services.Web.ImportAutoLiasse.IServiceImportAutoLiasse" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />

    <!--REST-->
    <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="SysLap.Services.Web.ImportAutoLiasse.IServiceImportAutoLiasse" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Please refer to the official document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/configuring-services-using-configuration-files

**Updated.**
The configured WCF service only works over HTTP protocol instead of HTTPS, for working over HTTPS, we need to configure an extra service endpoint using transport security mode.

```
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="myb">
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="restbeh"></endpoint>
      <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="restbeh" bindingConfiguration="httpsbinding"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="httpsbinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, 
I am sorry the mistake of the names it's my fault, it's good now I checked the name prperty and the contract,
but always still the same problem!
So what should do to fix it? Thanks

Comment: There are still some small errors in your code snippet, please double check and ask questions.

Comment: On my side, it works properly. please carefully check the invocation on the clients-side. there might be something wrong with the service address.

Comment: it's very weird! I modify my post: I add the service address, and it is ok the address,

Comment: I added to the post other inforation of the error , I get it in POSTMAN

Comment: In order to make the WCF Web Http service works over HTTPS protocol, we need to configure an extra service endpoint using transport security mode. please refer to the my updated reply.